# Inserting an enum result into a line of code C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I'm making a simple color picking script for a game that I've been working on. My problem is that I have to repeat these three lines for every color scheme that I have:

```
Robot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Salmon.Chenilles;

Robot.transform.Find("Middle").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Salmon.Cover;

Robot.transform.Find("Corps").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Salmon.Head;
```

I know that I should be able to not have to repeat myself, but I can't figure out how to insert my enum result into this line:

```
Robot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Slime.Chenilles;
```

I'd like to do something like this:

Robot.GetComponent().sprite = cPicker.(color.unit).Chenilles;

But obviously it doesn't work like that. Does anyone know how I could find a way to do this?
Thank you in advance.

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public enum ColorSelection { Slime, Salmon, Marine, Dusk }

[Serializable] public class ColorSet { public ColorSelection unit; }

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ColorPicker cPicker;

    public GameObject Robot;

    public ColorSet color;

    public void Update()
    {
        switch (color.unit)
        {
            case ColorSelection.Slime:
                Robot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Slime.Chenilles;
                Robot.transform.Find("Middle").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Slime.Cover;
                Robot.transform.Find("Corps").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Slime.Head;
                break;

            case ColorSelection.Salmon:
                Robot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Salmon.Chenilles;
                Robot.transform.Find("Middle").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Salmon.Cover;
                Robot.transform.Find("Corps").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Salmon.Head;
                break;

            case ColorSelection.Marine:
                Robot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Marine.Chenilles;
                Robot.transform.Find("Middle").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Marine.Cover;
                Robot.transform.Find("Corps").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Marine.Head;
                break;

            case ColorSelection.Dusk:
                Robot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Dusk.Chenilles;
                Robot.transform.Find("Middle").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Dusk.Cover;
                Robot.transform.Find("Corps").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cPicker.Dusk.Head;
                break;

        }

    }```
````

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding how `Chenilles` can be a member of an enum value like `Slime`. Does this code compile?

Comment: Can you change the ColorPicker type for a Dictionary<ColorSelection, whatever>? So you could do: cPicker[color.unit].Chenilles;

Comment: @robbpriestley I used the same word for a part of my enum and a ScriptableObject called Slime where I store all the sprites for that specific color scheme. So when Slime is picked in the enum, it sets the sprite to cPicker.Slime.Chenille and that fetches the "Chenille" Sprite in the "Slime" Scriptable Object in the "cPicker" ScriptableObject. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Stuart I'm not really sure, the ColorPicker is a scriptable object that stores all the color schemes. I'll try that but I have no Idea if or how it can be done, I'll go search on the unity scripting api

Comment: It is hard to understand what you mean, without seeing the declaration of the involved types. "enum" has a very specific meaning in C#: [enum (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can reduce the complexity of the code by having the switch expression return then type that has the object with the values on it, and the code that sets the sprites. This helps reduce a good amount of duplication. I could not infer the type, so I've called it `ColorType` here, please rename to the type current of `cPicker.Slime`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public enum ColorSelection { Slime, Salmon, Marine, Dusk }

[Serializable] public class ColorSet { public ColorSelection unit; }

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ColorPicker cPicker;

    public GameObject Robot;

    public ColorSet color;

    private ColorType GetColorType(ColorSelection colorSelection, ColorPicker colorPicker)
    {
        switch (colorSelection)
        {
            case ColorSelection.Slime:
                return colorPicker.Slime;
            case ColorSelection.Salmon:
                return colorPicker.Salmon;
            case ColorSelection.Marine:
                return colorPicker.Marine;
            case ColorSelection.Dusk:
                return colorPicker.Dusk;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(colorSelection), colorSelection, null);
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        var colorType = GetColorType(color.unit, cPicker);
        Robot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = colorType.Chenilles;
        Robot.transform.Find("Middle").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = colorType.Cover;
        Robot.transform.Find("Corps").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = colorType.Head;
    }
}
```

as a bonus, in C# 8.0 this can be reduced to a switch expression, making it even more concise:

```
private ColorType GetColorType(ColorSelection colorSelection, ColorPicker colorPicker) =>
    colorSelection switch
    {
        ColorSelection.Slime => colorPicker.Slime,
        ColorSelection.Salmon => colorPicker.Salmon,
        ColorSelection.Marine => colorPicker.Marine,
        ColorSelection.Dusk => colorPicker.Dusk,
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(colorSelection), colorSelection, null)
    };
```

Comment: Oh that looks way better ^^' But I don't really understand what "ColorType" is. I'm not too good at programming, is it something that I should call, or a type that I should define?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, that type is because I cannot infer it from your code.
If in your code you mouse over `cPicker.Marine`, the type will be shown, change it to that and it would work.

Comment: Oh, ok thank you very much! This is going to save me from having a headache tonight